How to create m2m relation for models in two files without direct imports in FastAPI and SQLModel?
I have fastAPI app with SQLModel. There are two folders with models.py files, each file has
an SQLModel model. Those models have many to many relation. I've created intermediate model to connect those two. I want to implement it without importing models directly, to avoid potential circular imports in future.
# documents/models.py
class Document(SQLModel, table=True):
  __tablename__ = "documents"
  id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
  name: str = Field(max_length=128)
  vehicles: list["Vehicle"] = Relationship(back_populates="documents", link_model=VehicleDocument)

class VehicleDocument(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "vehicle_documents"
    id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
    vehicle_id: int = Field(foreign_key="vehicles.id")
    document_id: int = Field(foreign_key="documents.id")

# vehicles/models.py
class Vehicle(VehicleBase, table=True):
  __tablename__ = "vehicles"
  id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
  documents: list["Document"] = Relationship(back_populates="vehicles", link_model=VehicleDocument)

To use it as it is I would need to import VehicleDocument from documents/models.py to vehicles/models.py. I want to avoid it. I've tried to use these options in the last line of code above:

link_model="VehicleDocument"
link_model="documents.models.VehicleDocument"
link_model="documents.models.vehicle_documents"

They failed with error :

"NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'str'>"

Is there another way I could achieve connecting those models?
